# $project split string and filter empty values

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Is there a way to split a string, then remove empty values from the array that was generated?

I have tried this, but the value of `path` is an **array of arrays** instead of an **array of strings**.

I was assuming that by using an array it would execute that in order but it doesn't seem to do that...

This is in the **$project**:

```
{
  path: [
    {
      $split: ['$filename', '/']
    }, {
      $filter: {
        input: '$path',
        as: 'str',
        cond: {
          $ne: ['$$str', '']
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Some example documents:

```
{ filename: '/a/b/c.txt' }
{ filename: '/abc/123.txt' }
{ filename: '/path/to/file.txt' }
```

Currently outputs:

```
{
  path: [
    ['', 'a', 'b', 'c.txt'],
    null
  ]
}
```

I would like:

```
{
  path: ['a', 'b', 'c.txt']
}
```

I am able to achieve this using 2 **$project** stages, but that seems redundant. Is it possible to do it in one stage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to do can be done in single [**`$project`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "path": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": { "$split": [ "$filename", "/" ] },
        "as": "str",
        "cond": {
          "$ne": [ "$$str", "" ]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Or with the  [**`$slice`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) and [**`$split`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split/) aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "path": {
      "$slice": [
        { "$split": [ "$filename", "/" ] },
        1,
        { "$size": { "$split": [ "$filename", "/" ] } }
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```